# В админке django не видно пользователей User

Tags: django, django-admin, django-model

Добавил после с зависимостью(ForeignKey) в модель и теперь при создании объекта запрашивается пользователь, но пользователей самих нет, хотя в админке зарегистрировано 3 пользователя.
Не знаю что теперь и делать, зависимость то мне нужна

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_image_dir, blank=True, default='avatars/default.webp')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    premium_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    quantity_todos = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 250, unique = True, null = True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username



class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        return f'{self.user.username}'


    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'
```

Добавил поле user в модель Category

Comment: Если вам нужна зависимость от юзера, значит так и надо писать `ForeignKey(User` а не Profile

Comment: Понял, спасибо.